# Changing batch,height,width,alpha to batch,alpha,height,width for pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have batch of images like

`torch.Size([10, 512, 512, 3])`

I can loop to the images and can see 10 images. But to feed this batch to pytorch i have to convert it to

`torch.Size([10, 3, 512, 512])`

I tried lot of ways but unable to get the solution for this

How can we do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `permute`:

```
import torch
x = torch.rand(10, 512, 512, 3)

y = x.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
```

`x.shape`: `torch.Size([10, 512, 512, 3])`

`y.shape`: `torch.Size([10, 3, 512, 512])`

Comment: because of changing the order it's adding the additional time. If you want to reduce the training time. You need to choose the optimizer and batch size wisely.